# create trigger for copying data from one table to dynamically generated table in postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, function, triggers

I have to simply copy data from one table to dynamically generated table. I created trigger for that..

```
CREATE  OR  REPLACE FUNCTION  historylogfunc() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $example_table$    
   DECLARE last_device_id text;
   BEGIN
        PERFORM last_device_id = device_id FROM company ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;        
    INSERT INTO "device_id"(emp_id, entry_date, name) VALUES (new.id,  current_timestamp,  new.name);
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$example_table$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

PERFORM last_device_id = device_id FROM company ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

It will select last `device_id` from table and store in var last `device_id`.
Suppose `device_id = dv001`,

I have to copy data from main table to new table i.e. dv001.

the error show: relation "device_id" does not exist.

Please help me...

Comment: Of course not - you want to insert into a table not into a String

Comment: You can't "insert" into a column. You insert into a **table**

Comment: PERFORM last_device_id = device_id FROM company ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;      This query calculate the last value of device_id column.. Each table is present for each new entry in device_id column.. Now i want to copy data at run time..

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with your function:

1. `PERFORM last_device_id = device_id FROM company ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;`

   - This is identical to `SELECT last_device_id = device_id FROM company ...;`, except that the result is discarded.
     So this statement does nothing since it has no side effects. That cannot be intended.
   - The (discarded) result of `SELECT last_device_id = device_id ...` is the `boolean` result of the comparison operator `=`. Is that what you intended?
2. `INSERT INTO "device_id"(emp_id, entry_date, name) VALUES (new.id, current_timestamp, new.name);`

   This causes the error message, because there is no table called `device_id`. Are you sure that there is a table of this name? Then maybe you have to qualify it with a schema name, if it is not in the `search_path`.
   But `device_id` looks more like a column name than a table name to me.

In the light of your comments below:

If you want to `INSERT` into a table whose name is the latest `device_id` entry in `company`, you'll have to use dynamic SQL like the following:

```
SELECT device_id INTO last_device_id
   FROM company
   ORDER BY id DESC
   LIMIT 1;
EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || quote_ident(last_device_id)
        || ' (emp_id, entry_date, name) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)'
   USING new.id,  current_timestamp,  new.name;
```

Comment: device_id is a column name in main_tbl, now when new entry is comes in main_tbl then it creates new table with that device_id value.. Suppose new entry with device_id  = dv005 is insert into main_tbl then it will create new table of name dv005.. it is created by third party so i have to simply copy data from main_tbl to newly created table..

Comment: @Ashish: why would you want to create a new table each time a row is inserted into main_table? That makes no sense whatsoever. (Also: `insert` doesn't create a new table, you would need `create table` for that)  What exactly are you trying to do here? What is the **real** problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Yes, I know that their is no sense to created new table for each time.. But that is the requirement.. And it is already done.. Now I have to only copy data to that newly created table.. Newly created table name is exact same as value in device_id column..

Comment: I have added a suggestion how this can be done to the answer.